# Htaccess Rewrite showing 404 not found

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this rewite rule in my htaccess file that removes index.php on the URL to just show the domain name

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php$ /$1 [L,R=302,NC,NE]
```

But it seems to show 404 not found on all other directories. For example, I have a directory called admin and if I go to www.domain.com/admin I get 404 not found

I also have this code above the RewriteCond code

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin [NC]
```

Here is my full htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/status [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/customer [NC]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php$ /$1 [L,R=302,NC,NE]

# Rewrites /services to be /home.php?id=services
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ /home.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]

#BLOG
# Rewrites /blog/this-is-a-blog-post to be /home.php?id=blog&slug=this-is-a-blog-post
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ /home.php?id=$1&slug=$2 [L,QSA]

# Rewrites /blog/year2013/month12 to be /home.php?id=blog&year=2013&month=01
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/year([0-9]+)/month([0-9]+)/?$ /home.php?id=$1&year=$2&month=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe services rules is causing problem here. Change that to:

```
# Rewrites /services to be /home.php?id=services
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ /home.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Do the same for blog rule also:

```
#BLOG
# Rewrites /blog/this-is-a-blog-post to be /home.php?id=blog&slug=this-is-a-blog-post
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ /home.php?id=$1&slug=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Is `/blog` an actual directory?

Comment: No it's not and it's also doing the same for all my pages. It's nit rewriting /services to home.php?id=services etc

Comment: I just provided your **Complete .htaccess** try that now.

Comment: It's working with the previous code.. I had the page name wrong. I forgot I had changed it from home.php to be index.php :)

Comment: Really great to know that it worked out. I will rollback latest changes to bring back original answer.